# Print formatted strings/char arrays in java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to format data from a database so everything is the same distance from one another (basically make it easier for your eyes). I am coming to the dilemma of the "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". I would love some help from the great community of stackoverflow to help me and many others solve this problem.

Hopefully I have just made a silly mistake and it doesn't have to be fully rewritten.

```
public static String formattedString(char[] c, int len1, char[] d, int len2,
      char[] e, int len3) {
    List<Character> charlist = new ArrayList<Character>(len1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
      if (c.length == len1 || c.length > len1) {
        charlist.add(c[i]);
      } else if (c.length < len2) {
        if (c.length < len1)
          charlist.add(c[i]);
        else
          charlist.add(' ');
      } else {
        charlist.add('#');
      }
    }
    List<Character> charlist2 = new ArrayList<Character>(len2);

    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
      if (d.length == len2 || d.length > len2) {
        charlist2.add(d[i]);
      } else if (d.length < len2) {
        if (d.length < len2)
          charlist2.add(d[i]);
        else
          charlist2.add(' ');
      } else {
        charlist2.add('#');
      }
    }
    List<Character> charlist3 = new ArrayList<Character>(len3);

    for (int i = 0; i < len3; i++) {
      if (e.length == len3 || e.length > len3) {
        charlist3.add(e[i]);
      } else if (e.length < len2) {
        if (i < len3)
          charlist3.add(e[i]);
        else
          charlist3.add(' ');
      } else {
        charlist3.add('#');
      }
    }

    String s = charlist.toString() + charlist2.toString()
        + charlist3.toString() + '\n';
    return s;
  }
```

to use the `formattedString` function you would do something like the following

```
try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table", user, password);
  Statement stmt = null;
  stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
     String username = rs.getString("user_name");
     double balance = rs.getDouble("balance");
     String b = balance + "";
     int accountID = rs.getInt("account_ID");
     String id = accountID + "";
     Q.print(Q.formattedString(username.toCharArray(), 10, b.toCharArray(), 15, id.toCharArray(), 10)); 
    // This is the proper way to use the function.
   }
 } catch (SQLException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Mind you that my issue is not the connecting to the DB but the formattedString function
**_______________________UPDATE_______________________**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
>     at co.kbcomp.java.server.usermanagement.Q.formatedString(Q.java:58)
>     at co.kbcomp.utils.Command.getAllUsers(Command.java:211)
>     at co.kbcomp.utils.Command.execute(Command.java:28)
>     at co.kbcomp.java.server.Main.(Main.java:27)
>     at co.kbcomp.java.server.StartServer.main(StartServer.java:5)

Comment: You should use a debugger to figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: What debugger do you recommend?

Comment: I use Eclipse. Choose your favorite IDE, it will almost definitely come with a debugger.

Comment: You do know about `System.out.printf`, right?

Comment: If you can give us the exact line where ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException occurs, it will help us to debug the program.

Comment: Well the funny thing is I'm not printing anything yet....

Comment: He means line of code where the exception is thrown..

Comment: I'll add it to the post, at the bottom.

Comment: It is where I add the character to the `charlist`(charlist, charlist2, and charlist3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to let everyone know about my solution which is as follows..

```
public static String formattedString(char[] c, int len1, char[] d, int len2, char[] e, int len3) {
    char[] charlist = new char[len1];
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
      if (c.length == len1 || c.length > len1) {
        charlist[i] = (c[i]);
      } else if (c.length < len1) { // <--here
        if (c.length > i)
          charlist[i] = (c[i]);
        else
          charlist[i] = ' ';
      } else {
        charlist[i] = '#';
      }
    }
    char[] charlist2 = new char[len2];

    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
      if (d.length == len2 || d.length > len2) {
        charlist2[i] = (d[i]);
      } else if (d.length < len2) {
        if (d.length > i)
          charlist2[i] = (d[i]);
        else
          charlist2[i] = ' ';
      } else {
        charlist2[i] = '#';
      }
    }
    char[] charlist3 = new char[len3];

    for (int i = 0; i < len3; i++) {
      if (e.length == len3 || e.length > len3) {
        charlist3[i] = (e[i]);
      } else if (e.length > i) { // <--here
        if (i < len3)
          charlist3[i] = (e[i]);
        else
          charlist3[i] = ' ';
      } else {
        charlist3[i] = '#';
      }
    }
    String s ="";
    int i = 0;
    for(char a : charlist){
      s += a;
    }
    for(char a : charlist2){
      s += a;
    }
    for(char a : charlist3){
      s += a;
    }

    return s+'\n';
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do it this way:

```
Q.formattedString(username.toCharArray(), username.length(), b.toCharArray(), b.length(), id.toCharArray(), id.length())
```

the error might occur when each of your string variables might contain string with the length less than the maximum length that you defined..
(10, 15, and 10 - for `username`, `b`, and `id` respectively)

Thus, it's better to measure each variable's length and use it as parameter..

**UPDATE**:

i see, so you want string with consistent length..

perhaps you just mistyped some variable names..

```
public static String formattedString(char[] c, int len1, char[] d, int len2,
      char[] e, int len3) {
    List<Character> charlist = new ArrayList<Character>(len1);
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
      if (c.length == len1 || c.length > len1) {
        charlist.add(c[i]);
      } else if (c.length < len1) { //<--here
        if (c.length < len1)
          charlist.add(c[i]);
        else
          charlist.add(' ');
      } else {
        charlist.add('#');
      }
    }
    List<Character> charlist2 = new ArrayList<Character>(len2);

    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
      if (d.length == len2 || d.length > len2) {
        charlist2.add(d[i]);
      } else if (d.length < len2) {
        if (d.length < len2)
          charlist2.add(d[i]);
        else
          charlist2.add(' ');
      } else {
        charlist2.add('#');
      }
    }
    List<Character> charlist3 = new ArrayList<Character>(len3);

    for (int i = 0; i < len3; i++) {
      if (e.length == len3 || e.length > len3) {
        charlist3.add(e[i]);
      } else if (e.length < len3) { //<--here
        if (i < len3)
          charlist3.add(e[i]);
        else
          charlist3.add(' ');
      } else {
        charlist3.add('#');
      }
    }

    String s = charlist.toString() + charlist2.toString()
        + charlist3.toString() + '\n';
    return s;
  }
```

Comment: My only issue with what I understand from this solution is that it will generate inconsistent string length. I am trying to get it set up like a html table.

Comment: i see.. maybe you had some typo..? please check my update..
notice that you had always used `len2`..

Comment: I got it to work by actually checking if c/d/e length was greater than i instead of len1/2/3. This way it is actually checking the char's position instead of if it was a specific length.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason ArrayIndesOutOfBoundsException can occur is because username.toCharArray(), b.toCharArray() and id.toCharArray()'s length is more than  10, 15 and 10 respectively.

Inside the formattedString function you access these arrays with c[i], d[i] and e[i] where i is supposed to be between 0 to 10, 15, 10 respectively.

Suggestion to remove this from happening is to print the length of username.toCharArray(), b.toCharArray() and id.charArray() and then making sure when you pass it to the function that it remains within bound of for loop variables.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do to prevent the ArrayIndesOutOfBoundsException is to add a space char to add length to the char array if the array length is less than the desired length

Comment: You are adding " " to charList, but it's c,d, e where the exception is coming from, their length is fixed. So when you access elements from them using c[i], d[i] or e[i] it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.